# Issue with getting thumbnail from videos in documents

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimage, avasset

I am trying to generating thumbnail from video files which stored in documents directory. First I am collecting only video files with `mp4` formats :

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        let VIDEO = [collect(files: "mp4"),
                     collect(files: "MP4")]
        videoArray = Array(VIDEO.joined())

    }


 func collect(files:String) -> [String] {

        var fileExtentions = [String]()

        let documentsUrl =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let keys = [URLResourceKey.isDirectoryKey, URLResourceKey.localizedNameKey]
        let options: FileManager.DirectoryEnumerationOptions = [.skipsPackageDescendants, .skipsSubdirectoryDescendants, .skipsHiddenFiles]

        let enumerator = fileManager.enumerator(
            at: documentsUrl,
            includingPropertiesForKeys: keys,
            options: options,
            errorHandler: {(url, error) -> Bool in
                return true
        })


        if enumerator != nil {
            while let file = enumerator!.nextObject() {
                let path = URL(fileURLWithPath: (file as! URL).absoluteString, relativeTo: documentsUrl).path
                if path.hasSuffix(files){
                    fileExtentions.append(path)
                }
            }
        }


        return fileExtentions
    }
```

Then fill tableview's data like this :

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! VideoCell

        let files = videoArray[indexPath.row]
        let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: files)

        //Vido Title
        cell.videoTitle.text = fileURL.lastPathComponent.removingPercentEncoding!


        cell.thumbnail.image = getThumbnailFrom(path:fileURL)

        return cell
    }
```

I am generating thumbnail from videos like this :

```
  func getThumbnailFrom(path: URL) -> UIImage? {

        do {

            let asset = AVURLAsset(url: path , options: nil)
            let imgGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
            imgGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
            let cgImage = try imgGenerator.copyCGImage(at: CMTimeMake(0, 5), actualTime: nil)
            let thumbnail = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)

            return thumbnail

        } catch let error {

            print("*** Error generating thumbnail: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return nil

        }

    }
```

But finally when run the app , compiler gives me this error :

> *** Error generating thumbnail: The requested URL was not found on this server.

Answer (score 1):

Finally fix the problem by finding the right `URL` :

```
let documentsURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!,isDirectory: true ) 

let urlToMyPath = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(fileURL.lastPathComponent.removingPercentEncoding!)!
```

Answer (score 0):

@Mc.Lover Tested getThumbnailFrom() function from my side. It is working fine at my side. Probably you might have to check whether the path url is correct. Otherwise it could be an issue with the set of video files you have.

Below is the code I tested.

```
func getThumbnailFrom() -> UIImage? {

    do {
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Video_05", ofType:"mp4")!
        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: path) , options: nil)
        let imgGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
        imgGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
        let cgImage = try imgGenerator.copyCGImage(at: CMTimeMake(0, 5), actualTime: nil)
        let thumbnail = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)

        return thumbnail

    } catch let error {

        print("*** Error generating thumbnail: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return nil

    }

}
```

Comment: What is you url path ? can you paste it here ?

Comment: Below is the url I checked in my simulator. "file:///Users/shreekara/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7E7EF505-E943-40FB-97EB-08EF91B0F7C4/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/589A03B8-A487-4986-888B-69ABE26CF5AE/TextDisplay.app/Video_05.mp4"

Comment: you checked this with `Bundle.main.pathFor...` ?

Comment: I need it for document directory